# How to inject content scripts on source less iframe in firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, content-script

content scripts is working on chrome but for firefox it is not working

I tired using match_about_blank set to true, but no success, I have seen the documentations on firefox doc but it is not documented properly on how to solve the issue.

Comment: It may be a bug in Firefox e.g. if the iframe has a `sandbox` attribute. Also note that just because it doesn't have `src` doesn't mean it wasn't navigated to a different URL inside. Select the iframe in devtools console's [iframe menu](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/_images/developer_tools_select_iframe.png) and then run `location.href`.

Comment: @wOxxOm it is populated using write method dynamically using a script on the website. for example `document.write(<div>heelo</div>)`

Comment: You can use MutationObserver (or overwrite wrappedJSObject.document.write) in the main page to detect this iframe and then access it directly via iframeElem.contentDocument.

Comment: @wOxxOm Please can you give an example with the code it will be very helpful